# Background Image scrolling with elements on Phones (android, ios)

Tags: html, css

I made a responsive view and now I have a problem with scrolling content on phone. To be more precise, the problem is that my absolute positioned elements are scrolling with the content. Example:

```css
.days {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 15px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.fade-left {
  padding: 0 !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 37px;
  background: url('../Images/left-opacity.png');
}
.days div {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  color: #a4b5bf;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="days">
   <div class="fade-left"></div>
   <div class="fade-right"></div>
   <div>Attendance to date</div>
   <div>Attendance this Year</div>
   <div>Absence Pattern</div>
</div>
```

Whenever I start scrolling , the fade-left/right start scrolling with my elements inside days div. They are not fixed on the sides, that is what I need. Those elements should stay on sides while the content is being scrolled.

Note that this behavior is only on phones, not in chrome console or other browsers.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/k2qzfz3m/ here is a jsfiddle with the issue, I want my white boxes to be stay on the edge of the parent div, not to be scrolled with other content. Position fixed is not an option since I have more content and on the page.

Comment: its most likely `display: flex;` causing that.

Comment: @LewisBrowne I tried with display: block; and divs inline-block, same problem. The shadow stays on top of the first div, when i click on next div it shows where it should, but on scroll it moves..

Comment: Could you put it into a jsfiddle for me?

Comment: @LewisBrowne Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/k2qzfz3m/ . This is actually the problem I wanted to display, I want my white elements to stay fixed on that spot while I scroll. I can't set them to fixed since I have more content and I want them to be inside this .days div only.